# How to access a view in spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I see you can [create views](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/views#getting_information_about_a_view) in spanner (awesome!). My use case is for our analytics, we often have to do joins constantly and having a view seems to make it accessible by our app.

But in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/views#getting_information_about_a_view), I see we cannot access them via the read api. How can I access it then? In the documentation, it says "Views can provide logical data-modeling to applications", which makes me think there must be a way to access.

Where in the documentation can I read how my application can access this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access a view in the same way as a table in a SQL query. So assume that you have this data model:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Singers (
  SingerId STRING(36) NOT NULL,
  FirstName STRING(200),
  LastName  STRING(200),
) PRIMARY KEY (SingerId);

CREATE VIEW SingersView SQL SECURITY INVOKER AS 
SELECT SingerId AS SingerId, CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS FullName
FROM Singers
ORDER BY LastName;
```

The you can do for example the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM SingersView;

SELECT FullName FROM SingersView;

SELECT s.FirstName, s.LastName, sv.FullName
FROM Singers s
INNER JOIN SingersView sv ON s.SingerId=sv.SingerId;
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn’t find this in the documentation. So you know where it would be ? It would help me look in the right place before asking.